# The Kabbalistic aspect of Gemara Rashi, Tosfos

Tags: talmud-gemara, mysticism-kabbalah

Are there any sources that talk about the Kabbalistic aspect of Gemara Rashi Tosfos? The effect it has in ones life and the upper worlds?

Comment: I'm confised, do you mean Gemmorah or Rashi or Tosfos (either of them) or you mean Gemmora's Rashi and Gemmorah's Tosfos?

Comment: Traditionally, the Rishonim were "unaware" of Sefer Hazoar (allegedly our "source" of the Kabbalah) as it was "unearthed" some 500 years later. Therefore they didn't have the Kabbalic tradition. Although many later Rabbis found *some of their statements* aligned with Sefer Hazoar or AriZL's teachings.

Answer (score -1):

All Gemara is Torah.
Not all Torah is Gemara:
Some Torah is Gemara.

I searched 'אורייתא' under Zohar at Sefaria.

[1.4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.4b.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> בְּרֵאשִׁית רִבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן פָּתַח (ישעיהו נ״א:ט״ו-ט״ז) וָאָשִׂים דְּבָרַי בְּפִיךָ. כַּמָּה אִית לֵיהּ לְבַר נָשׁ לְאִשְׁתַּדְּלָא בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא יְמָמָא וְלֵילְיָא, בְּגִין דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא צַיִּית לְקָלְהוֹן דְּאִנּוּן דְּמִתְעַסְּקֵי בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, וּבְכָל מִלָּה דְאִתְחַדָּשׁ בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא עַל יְדָא דְהַהוּא דְּאִשְׁתַּדַּל בְּאוֹרַיְתָא, עָבִיד רְקִיעָא חָדָא.
>
> Beresheet: Rabbi Shimon opened: “Put my words in your mouth. How much effort should man exert in the Torah day and night, for the Creator is attentive to those who study it. And with every word that man attains by his efforts in the Torah, he builds a firmament.”

[1.12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.12b.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> דְּכֵיוָן דְּבַר נָשׁ אִתְעַסַּק בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא (נח ס''ב ע''א) אִתְתַּקַּן (ש''כ ע''א) בְּנִשְׁמָתָא אָחֳרָא קַדִּישָׁא. דִּכְתִיב שֶׁרֶץ נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה. נֶפֶשׁ דְּהַהִיא חַיָּה קַדִּישָׁא. דְּכַד בַּר נָשׁ לָא אִתְעַסַּק בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא לֵית לֵיהּ נַפְשָׁא קַדִּישָׁא. קְדוּשָׁא דִּלְעֵילָא לָא שַׁרְיָא עֲלוֹי. וְכַד אִשְׁתַּדַּל בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, בְּהַהוּא רְחִישׁוּ דְּרָחִישׁ בָּהּ זָכֵי לְהַהִיא נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה, וּלְמֶהֱדַר כְּמַלְאָכִין קַדִּישִׁין. דִּכְתִיב, (תהילים ק״ג:כ׳) בָּרְכוּ יְיָ מַלְאָכָיו, אִלֵּין אִנּוּן דְּמִתְעַסְּקִין בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא דְּאִקְרוּן מַלְאָכָיו בְּאַרְעָא.
>
> ...One who who is busy in Torah gets another holy soul (or breath?), and one who does not, does not... Through Torah one can be like a holy angel... on earth.

[2.200a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.199b.11-200a.2?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi)

> רִבִּי חִיָּיא פָּתַח וְאָמַר,
>   (שמות לה) קְחוּ מֵאִתְּכֶם תְּרוּמָה לַיְיָ'. תָּא חֲזֵי קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא כַּד בָּרָא עָלְמָא, לָא בָּרָא לֵיהּ, אֶלָּא בְּגִין דְּיִיִתוּן יִשְׂרָאֵל, וִיקַבְּלוּן אוֹרַיְיתָא. בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא אִתְבְּרֵי עָלְמָא, וְעַל אוֹרַיְיתָא קַיְּימָא. הֲדָא הוּא דִּכְתִּיב, (ירמיה לג) אִם לא בְרִיתִי יוֹמָם וָלָיְלָה חֻקּוֹת שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ לֹא שָׂמְתִּי. אוֹרַיְיתָא אִיהִי אַרְכָּא דְּחַיֵּי בְּהַאי עָלְמָא, וְאַרְכָּא דְּחַיֵּי בְּעָלְמָא דְּאָתֵי.
>   וְכָל מַאן דְּאִשְׁתַּדָל בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, כְּאִלוּ אִשְׁתָּדַּל בְּהֵיכָלֵיהּ דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא. דְּהֵיכְלָא עִלָּאָה דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, אוֹרַיְיתָא אִיהִי. וְכַד בַּר נָשׁ עָסִיק בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא קָאִים תַּמָּן, וְאָצִית לְקָלֵיהּ, כְּמָה דִּכְתִּיב, (מלאכי ג) וַיַּקְשֵׁב יְיָ' וַיִּשְׁמָע וְגוֹ'. וְאִשְׁתְּזִיב בַּר נָשׁ מִתְּלַת דִּינִין: מִדִּינָא דְּהַאי עָלְמָא. וּמִדִּינָא דְּמַלְאָךְ הַמָּוְת, דְּלָא יָכִיל לְשַׁלְּטָאָה עָלֶיהָ. וּמִדִּינָא דְּגֵיהִנָּם.
>
> God created the world for Torah, and it is sustained on Torah... Torah is the length of days in this world and the next. One who learns Torah is as if he has served in the in God's heichel... When one is busy with Torah God is there with him, and listens to his voice. Man is saved from the judgement of this world and from the the angel of death and from judgement of gehenom through Torah.

[3.152b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.152b.3-5?lang=bi)

> וְאִי נִשְׁמָתִין חָמְרִיִּים, דְּאִינּוּן כְּמָאנֵי חֶרֶס, שְׁבִירָתָן זוֹ הִיא טַהֲרָתָן. כְּמָה דְאַתְּ אָמֵר נִשְׁבָּרוּ, נִטְהָרוּ. וְרָזָא דְּמִלָּה, (תהילים נ״א:י״ט) זִבְחֵי אֱלֹהִים רוּחַ נִשְׁבָּרָה וְגוֹ'. אֲבָל אִינּוּן דְּמִשְׁתַּדְּלִין בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא דְּבִכְתָב וּבְאוֹרַיְיתָא דְבְּעַל פֶּה, דְּאִינּוּן אֵשׁ וּמַיִם, וְאִינּוּן דְּמִשְׁתַּדְּלִין בְּרָזֵי דְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, דְּאִיהוּ אוֹר, דִּכְתִּיב בָּהּ, (משלי ו׳:כ״ג) וְתוֹרָה אוֹר, בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא אִינּוּן מִתְדַּכִין בָּה.
>   וְעוֹד בְּפֶרֶק הָרוֹאֶה, הָרוֹאֶה תְּמָרִים בַּחֲלוֹם, תַּמּוּ עֲוֹנוֹתָיו. הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב, (איכה ד׳:כ״ב) תַּם עֲוֹנֵךְ בַּת צִּיּוֹן. בְּגִין דִּתְמָרִים, בֵּיהּ תַּם, דַּרְגָא דְּיַעֲקֹב, דְּאִתְּמַר בֵּיהּ, (בראשית כ״ה:כ״ז) וְיַעֲקֹב אִישׁ תָּם. חוֹבִין מָרִים, וְעַל דָּא תְּמָרִים: תַּמָּן תָּ''ם, וְתַמָּן מָ''ר.
>   הָכָא רָמִיז, וַיִמְתְּקוּ הַמָּיִם. הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב, (שמות ט״ו:כ״ה) וַיּוֹרֵהוּ יְיָ עֵץ וַיִמְתְּקוּ הַמָּיִם. מֵהָכָא, מַאן דְּאִשְׁתְּדַּל בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, דְּאִיהוּ עֵץ. חוֹבִין דִּילֵיהּ, דְּאִתְּמַר בְּהוֹן (שמות א׳:י״ד) וַיְמָרַרוּ אֶת חַיִּיהֶם בַּעֲבוֹדָה קָשָׁה, קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא מָחִיל לֵיהּ, וְיִתְחַזְרוּן מְתִיקִין.
>
> Written Torah and Oral Torah is like fire and water... they cleanse the learner...God forgives those who learn Torah.

Comment: This is Torah Sheba'al Peh in general, not Gemara-Rashi-Tosfos in particular.

Comment: Are you sure all Gemara is Torah? Isn't some of it medicine, husbandry, agriculture, astronomy, etc.? Also see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65974/is-the-talmud-100-oral-torah/93509#93509).

Comment: Are you claiming that learning parts of the Gemara would not fall under learning Torah? What is Torah learning if not things found in the physical world guided by Torah principal @Alex

Comment: A man is all human, surely he is other things as well like a father and brother, but he is all human @Alex

Comment: As stated, the underlying action of Tosfos and Gemara is what the Zohar calls just learning Torah (or the other verbs it employs as well), therefore this is valid @DonielF

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Again, it’s very nice that this talks about Torah SheBa’al Peh, which includes Gemara. But the OP asked specifically about Gemara, not about Torah SheBa’al Peh in general.

Comment: but arent you doing the same mechanincal movements @Don

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel No, not necessarily. Like you yourself said - “All Gemara is Torah. Not all Torah is Gemara.” This all is true of Torah in general, but the OP supposes there’s something special about Gemara-Rashi-Tosfos.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel The Torah aspects of the physical world would be Torah. But why would a mere discussion about the physical world itself be Torah? Just because it was said by amoraim? If the rabbi talks about the Super Bowl does it become Torah because he is the rabbi?